# Permission Denied for apropos command

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, permission

I'm trying to list the contents of the whole `apropos` (`makewhatis`) database with the following command but I keep getting `Permission denied`.

`sudo -s apropos . > touch thedatabase`

`-bash: touch: Permission denied`

---

`sudo -s apropos . > thedirectory`

`thedatabase: Permission denied`

---

`apropos . > touch thedatabase`

---

All of these result in some form of `Permission Denied`. How do I get around this or what is the more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but have a couple of observations that may help: 1) The redirect is interpreted in the current shell, not the sudo shell, so if you're in a directory you can't write to as a normal user, that could cause a permission denied; 2) the first word after the redirect is the file to redirect to, so the first example is equivalent to `sudo -s apropos . thedatabase > touch`, and similarly the last example. Maybe just try `apropos . >/tmp/ap.out`, you should be able to write to /tmp.

Comment: @blm First of you were right, my problem was that I was in a non-authorized directory. To be clear, the redirect is`>` correct? And how does your example of of putting `thedatabase` _before_ `> touch` make sense? I don't think I have a solid grasp of the ordering that these things can be in. Thank you!

Comment: My example with thedatabase before > isn't really an example, it's what your first example is doing. While redirects are normally put at the end of a command, they don't have to be, For example, `echo hello >echo.out` is how one would normally write a command to echo a line containing "hello" to the file echo.out, but `echo >echo.out hello` and `>echo.out echo hello` do the same thing. So in your first example, the shell sees `> touch` and treats that as a redirect to the file touch, then when it sees `thedatabase`, it's treated as just another command argument.

Comment: awesome, that makes perfect sense. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do what you are asking.  Looking into that now, but I know how to get around the permissions problems you are having with sudo.

Your syntax is wrong for sudo, the shell redirection ">" is happening without elevated privelleges.  Try wrapping in quotes like this:

```
sudo -s 'apropos . > touch thedatabase'
```